# Android Deeplinking not working with multiple schemes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter, deep-linking

I am stuck with the following scenario. I defined the following deep link intent filters in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Expected behavior is when I found a url of format `http://​www.domain.com/a/blabla` or when there is link in SMS/eMail of format `domain/xyz` the system should trigger my activity.

Case #1: Working fine

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MYActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="xyz"
                android:scheme="domain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Case #2: Working fine

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MYActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data
                android:scheme="http" 
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/a"
             />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Case #3: NOT working

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MYActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="xyz"
                android:scheme="domain" />
             <data
                android:scheme="http" 
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/a"
             />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any suggestions/points/help is really appreciated

Comment: TL;DR: `host` and `pathPrefix` *have to* be the same in one `intent-filter`. You can duplicate `data` elements in one `intent-filter` with different `scheme`. Example: http and https version of the same host/pathPrefix can be in one intent filter.

Comment: @EugenPechanec your comment could be a valid answer to this question. It's easier to link to an answer than a comment in a Code Review :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/H4ae9Jv5B3I?t=143. this google developer does it the way you said. do you think google updated the code to make it work

Comment: @EugenPechanec What do you mean by that? I've found the exact opposite to the be the case. Multiple pathPrefix are fine, but multiple scheme are not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I placed both the deeplinks in two different intent filters and it worked!!!.

Comment: can you post your working code? I'm having trouble with two different intent filter

Comment: @Renges what is the error you are seeing ? What is the isssue ?

Comment: It works with http and custom scheme when I test with terminal but when my friend put the website up and pass the custom url schemce,it does not open my app

Comment: Is it possible to share the custom url (deeplink schema) and your manifest. For ex: Our custom deeplink looks like this - 'domain://path/deeplink'; our actual url looks like this - 'http://www.domain.com/a/b/path' -

Comment: @Blanc are you using the same action and categories in the different intent filter? for ex:  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

Comment: @SoH Yes we did had action and category info along with the intent filters.

Comment: this is strange, the google developer here puts it all in the same intent filter: https://youtu.be/H4ae9Jv5B3I?t=143

Answer (score 16):

See the documentation of [`<data>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html): it states that:

> All the `<data>` elements contained within the same `<intent-filter>` element contribute to the same filter.

Hence

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="xyz"
        android:scheme="domain" />
    <data
        android:scheme="http" 
        android:host="www.domain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/a" />
<intent-filter>
```

is interpreted equivalently as (not real code)

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="xyz"
        android:scheme="domain"
        android:scheme="http" 
        android:host="www.domain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/a" />
<intent-filter>
```

which clearly has some contradictions, for example host being `xyz` VS `www.domain.com`.

Comment: Okay. So it means I cannot have different hosts in same intent filter. I will try keeping them in different intent filters. Appreciate your comments

Comment: I highly suggest reading those docs of `<data>` and `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: In what version of android duplicate scheme is supported, i don't think its not possible as per XSD...

Comment: @whoami the second code block is pseudo-xml, not valid. I just put it there to get the point through to see the contradictions.

Answer (score 9):

From Android official documentation site :

> Although it's possible to include multiple  elements in the same
>   filter, **it's important that you create separate filters when your
>   intention is to declare unique URLs** (such as a specific combination of
>   scheme and host), because multiple  elements in the same intent
>   filter are actually merged together to account for all variations of
>   their combined attributes.

You will have to create separate `intent-filter`s.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but relates the the OP question above with extra information that might help someone else.

If you have intent filters with **deeplinks across multiple manifests** and want to merge them **without overriding each other** you can add a unique `android:label` on your `<intent-filter>`.

---

Example:

`main/AndroidManifest.xml`
*(These deeplinks are available to `all` app flavours, `debug`, `prodcution` etc)*

```
<intent-filter android:label="main_deeplink1">
    <data
        android:host="domain.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
<intent-filter>
```

---

`debug/AndroidManifest.xml`
*(These deeplinks are available only to the `debug` build flavour)*

```
<intent-filter android:label="debug_deeplink1">
    <data
        android:host="dev.domain.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
<intent-filter>
```

The merged Manifest file will now contain both deeplinks without overriding each other.